# VS Code tunnel extension, whitelist for outbound SSH connections

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, proxy, tunnel

I am trying to use the tunnel extension in Visual Studio Code to connect to a server, but I'm having trouble doing it in my office. My guess is that the problem is due to SSH outbound connections being restricted.

I would like to ask our IT administrator to add the necessary servers to the whitelist. Could anyone provide information about the servers or addresses tunnel connects to, or tell me which servers need to be whitelisted in order to use the tunnel extension on Visual Studio Code properly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To establish a connection, I attempted to use the tunnel extension in VS Code to establish a connection with a remote server, as written in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels.
However, I encountered issues related to outbound SSH connections, presumably due to certain restrictions in my office. I tried setting up an HTTP proxy, but it didn't improve the situation.

Due to reasons on the remote server side, I was instructed to use the tunnel extension instead of the VS Code SSH.